# Error while trying to add CI to a python project

Tags: python, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am trying to add Travis Ci tests to a python project but everytime I run it I have an error saying:

```
Setting APT mirror in /etc/apt/sources.list: http://us-east- 
1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
3.1 is not installed; attempting download
Downloading archive: https://s3.amazonaws.com/travis-python- 
archives/binaries/ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/python-3.1.tar.bz2
$ curl -sSf -o python-3.1.tar.bz2 ${archive_url}
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
Unable to download 3.1 archive. The archive may not exist. Please consider a 
different version.
```

This is the travis.yml file :

```
language: python
python:
 - "3.1"
install: pip install -r requirements.txt
script: 
- python tests.py
```

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour]. No one is going to visit that link, which will be dead in an internet moment. Provide a [mcve] and describe what you want to do. Show any errors or messages as _formatted_ text. You can always [edit] your question. Remember that comments are not part of the question.

Comment: I think this version is better than the other one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is telling you that Python 3.1 is not a version that Travis supports, please try a newer version like

```
language: python
python:
 - "3.6"
```